# Loopback find and update in model array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

I have a model for a project as follows:

```
{
  "name": "Project 1",
  "members":[{userId: 1, isAdmin: false}, {userId: 2, isAdmin: false}]
}
```

Using loopback (node.js server side code), how would I go about finding a project that has `userId=1` and remove it from the array?

```
Project.updateAttributes({...?...},{...?...}, function(err,info){

})
```